# Multi-platform social networking application development architecture

Tags: performance, architecture, scalability, social-networking, development-environment

I was thinking on some social media applications like facebook or linkedin. I read lots of articles on websites like http://highscalability.com/ and didn't find the correct answer.

Because, the biggest apps of now, use their custom systems. They use custom file systems or customized db-engines or customized web servers. They don't use the original iis, apache, mssql, mysql, windows or linux. They use lots of programming language for different problems. It's OK for them because of their load. They have to calculate every bit or something. They started on some small enviroments and they encountered problems and saw bottlenecks. So they founded new solutions.

Now, we can find some articles about their current systems. But we have no answer about **what is the best start**.

I need to learn the answer of **"What kind of architecture is a correct start?"**

I have some ideas on it but we need to be sure about it.

We think,

Use mysql for relational database. And a caching mechanism like memcached over mysql. And a rest api for business layer. We think using python for codding of rest api. And all systems run on a suitable linux distro. After all of these enviroments is ok, we can use any language or system for UIs. It can be a PHP site for web or a native application for IOS or Android.

We need your advice. Thank you so much.

(I am a good reader but it's my first question. I hope there's no problem.)

Comment: From your blind point of view that may be “correct”. From my blind point of view a Windows-based stack may be “correct”. This is not a feasible question. You are looking for a solution but didn't specify the problem.

Comment: I don't agree with the sentiment of the "on hold". As you can see in my answer this is not a matter of opinon but a matter of choosing appropriate options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following a similar question last year I [compiled](http://bit.ly/1f1xiJk) the techniques and technologies used by some of the larger social networking sites.

The following architecture concepts are prevalent among such sites:

Scalability

- Caching (heavily, across multiple tiers and layers)
- Data Sharding (preferrably by data-locality criteria)
- In-Memory DBs for often referenced data
- Efficient wire-level protocols (as opposed to what an enterprise typically considers state of the art)
- asynchronous processing

Flexibility

- service oriented architecture as a baseline principle
- decoupled and layered components
- asynchronous processing

Reliability

- asynchronous processing
- replication
- cell architecture (independently operated subsets, e.g. by geographical criteria)

NB: If you start a new site, you are unlikely to have the kind of scaling or reliability requirements that these extremely large sites face. Hence the best advice is to start small but keep it flexible. One approach is to use an application framework that starts out simple but has flexibility to scale later, e.g. Django.

Comment: Really thank you. Specially the slide that you shared is so helpful for me. My biggest problem is the business layer. Should it be a private API ? It can be a rest API or else. But should it be an API works over HTTP? Is it expensive ? I think "Apache Thrift" will tell me what I need. Thx again.

Comment: glad if it helps. I recommend starting small - write the business layer as local callable (same box initially), then add a REST API on top of it. For the API, distinguish between technology (e.g. REST, WS*/SOAP, assuming HTTP as the transport seems fair) and business semantics which defines the actual objects and operations. For the technology use existing frameworks and plugins wherever possible, don't reinvent the wheel unless you absolutely have to because no one has solved your particular problem yet. For the business semantics I would start with your own "private" API for simplicity.